# JavaScript variable is not updating properly with calculator app

Tags: javascript

I am creating a calculator app using HTML, CSS, and JS as my stack.

When the user attempts to inputs a number, the behavior of the calculator is fine with single-digit arithmetic. However, as soon as the user attempts to input any number longer than two digits, the calculator drops all of the digits except for the first of both numbers and then proceeds to execute the arithmetic.

```js
// Initializing all variables
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current");
const previousDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous");

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');

const clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete");
const enterButton = document.querySelector(".enter");
const pointButton = document.querySelector(".point");


let firstNumber;
let secondNumber;
let operand;
let answer;

// Adding event listeners to all buttons
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearAll);
enterButton.addEventListener('click', enter);

numberButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /* 
        Checks if firstNumber is assigned yet.

        If firstNumber & operand is undefined, just assign value of button to firstNumber.

        If firstNumber has a value assigned and the operand is undefined, that means they pressed a number button already, append and reassign to firstNumber.

        If secondNumber and operand is defined, then we know the user is appending to the secondNumber

        Else they are just beginning to type their secondNumber.
        */

        if (isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) { 
            firstNumber = parseFloat(button.textContent); 
            currentDisplay.textContent = firstNumber;
            console.log("Case 1: firstNumber: " + firstNumber);
        } else if (!isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            firstNumber = parseFloat(currentDisplay.textContent);
            console.log("Case 2: firstNumber: " + firstNumber);
        } else if (!isUndefined(secondNumber) && !isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            secondNumber = parseFloat(currentDisplay.textContent);
            console.log("Case 1: secondNumber: " + secondNumber);
        } else {
            secondNumber = parseFloat(button.textContent);
            currentDisplay.textContent = secondNumber;
            console.log("Case 2: secondNumber: " + secondNumber);
        }
}));

operationButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /*
        Checks if there is the operand & firstNumber has been assigned yet.

        If both the operand and firstNumber is undefined, then they are trying to do some sort of arithemtic with zero (aka the starting value).

        If the operand is undefined but the firstNumber isn't, that means the user has finished inputting their number and are moving onto an arithmetic operation. 
        */

        if (isUndefined(operand) && !isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }

        if (isUndefined(operand) && isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }
}));


function appendToCurrent(number) {
    currentDisplay.textContent += number
}

function appendToPrevious(op) {
    /* 
    Takes in a button (which contains the operand) and assigns it to the 'operand' variable. Moves currentDisplay to previousDisplay while appending the operand to it. Afterwards, clear the currentDisplay readying it for new user input.
    */

    previousDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent; 
    previousDisplay.textContent += op;
    clear(currentDisplay);
}

function isUndefined(variable) {
    return variable === undefined;
}

function del() {
    
}

function enter() {
    console.log(operand + (typeof operand));
    switch (operand.trim()) {
        case "+":
            console.log("Case: Addition");
            answer = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        case "-":
            console.log("Case: Subtraction");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            answer = subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        case "/":
            console.log("Case: Division");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            answer = divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        case "*":
            console.log("Case: Multiplication");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            answer = multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Case: Default");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            break;
    }
}

function clearAll() {
    currentDisplay.textContent = 0;
    previousDisplay.textContent = ' ';

    firstNumber = undefined;
    secondNumber = undefined;
    operand = undefined;

    console.clear();
}

function clear(display) {
    display.textContent = ' ';
}

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function divide (x, y) {
    return x / y;
}
```

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* Main app */
.app {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.calculator {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.display {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: right;
    word-break: break-all;

    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    border: 1.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.current {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.previous {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    gap: 20px;
}

#button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.zero {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

.enter {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?vfquery=fira">
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="display">
                    <div class="previous"></div>
                    <div class="current">0</div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button id="button" class="clear">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="delete">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation="">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation> 
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="enter">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="zero" data-number>
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="point">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one `id="button"`. **It must be unambigously pointing to one element only.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be in the `appendToCurrent()` function. You need to trim the `number` parameter before you add it to the current number:

```
function appendToCurrent(number) 
{
  const newNumber = currentDisplay.textContent += number.trim()
  return newNumber
}
```

```js
// Initializing all variables
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current");
const previousDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous");

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');

const clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete");
const enterButton = document.querySelector(".enter");
const pointButton = document.querySelector(".point");


let firstNumber;
let secondNumber;
let operand;
let answer;

// Adding event listeners to all buttons
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearAll);
enterButton.addEventListener('click', enter);

numberButtons.forEach(button =>
{
  button.addEventListener('click', () => 
  {
    /* 
    Checks if firstNumber is assigned yet.

    If firstNumber & operand is undefined, just assign value of button to firstNumber.

    If firstNumber has a value assigned and the operand is undefined, that means they pressed a number button already, append and reassign to firstNumber.

    If secondNumber and operand is defined, then we know the user is appending to the secondNumber

    Else they are just beginning to type their secondNumber.
    */

    if (isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) 
    {
      firstNumber = parseFloat(button.textContent);
      currentDisplay.textContent = firstNumber;
    } 
    else if (!isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) 
    {
      appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
      firstNumber = parseFloat(currentDisplay.textContent);
    } 
    else if (!isUndefined(secondNumber) && !isUndefined(operand)) 
    {
      appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
      secondNumber = parseFloat(currentDisplay.textContent);
    } 
    else 
    {
      secondNumber = parseFloat(button.textContent);
      currentDisplay.textContent = secondNumber;
    }
  })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /*
    Checks if there is the operand & firstNumber has been assigned yet.

    If both the operand and firstNumber is undefined, then they are trying to do some sort of arithemtic with zero (aka the starting value).

    If the operand is undefined but the firstNumber isn't, that means the user has finished inputting their number and are moving onto an arithmetic operation. 
    */

    if (isUndefined(operand) && !isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
      operand = button.textContent;
      appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
    }

    if (isUndefined(operand) && isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
      operand = button.textContent;
      appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
    }
  }));


function appendToCurrent(number) 
{
  const newNumber = currentDisplay.textContent += number.trim()
  return newNumber
}

function appendToPrevious(op) {
  /* 
  Takes in a button (which contains the operand) and assigns it to the 'operand' variable. Moves currentDisplay to previousDisplay while appending the operand to it. Afterwards, clear the currentDisplay readying it for new user input.
  */

  previousDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent;
  previousDisplay.textContent += op;
  clear(currentDisplay);
}

function isUndefined(variable) {
  return variable === undefined;
}

function del() {

}

function enter() {

  switch (operand.trim()) {
    case "+":
      answer = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
      previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
      currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
      break;
    case "-":
      previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
      answer = subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
      currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
      break;
    case "/":
      previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
      answer = divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
      currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
      break;
    case "*":
      previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
      answer = multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
      currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
      break;
    default:
      previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
      break;
  }
}

function clearAll() {
  currentDisplay.textContent = 0;
  previousDisplay.textContent = ' ';

  firstNumber = undefined;
  secondNumber = undefined;
  operand = undefined;

  console.clear();
}

function clear(display) {
  display.textContent = ' ';
}

function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
  return x - y;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}

function divide(x, y) {
  return x / y;
}
```

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
  display: none;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: lightgray;
}


/* Main app */

.app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.calculator {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.display {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: right;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.current {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.previous {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

#button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.zero {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.enter {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="previous"></div>
      <div class="current">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="button" class="clear">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" class="delete">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-operation="">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-operation> 
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
      <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" class="enter">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" class="zero" data-number>
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
      <button id="button" class="point">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is happening under the hood when I do not trim it?

Comment: @DannyChen All of the `button.textContent` values have spaces around them. When you type the first number, it hits the first if statement `numberButtons.forEach` loop and `parseFloat()` is called before it is displayed, which trims it. The second number (e.g. the "0" in "10") hits the second if statement and you call `appendToCurrent()` before `parseFloat()`, so you're trying to add the spaced out string to a number.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had the same issue with one of my previous posts and it turned out to be the same issue again. For better practice, should I stop putting spaces within elements in my HTML?

Comment: @DannyChen No, I think best practice would be to format all of the numbers in Javascript via `parseFloat()` or a similar function, as high up in the click event as possible.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I would do so, either using my example or somebody else's?

Comment: @DannyChen maybe later if I get a chance. Now that I look more closely at your code, I think it is fine as it is, because I would need to refactor it to move the `parseFloat()` function up.